# How to adjust this two series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, optimization

I'm struggling with a problem of fitting two series of numbers (I'm using Excel). Let's go:

I have two series (A, B), consisting of several points recorded over time (a1, a2, a3...; b1, b2, b3...). Each series has different units (A="$", B="km"). I want to apply the formula (B'=mB+n) in order to have B' with the maximum possible correlation with A.

As an example:

A = (5,8,9,6,10,8 )
B = (4,5,6,5,7,5)
If m=2 and n=-3 then B'= (5,7,9,7,11,7)

Could you please explain to me to find the parameters "m" and "n" of the formula that give the maximum correlation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a linear regression analysis. If you are using Excel, you can perform it by simply creating a graph (scatterplot type) and then activating the regression line option.

Comment: No sorry, that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to fit a regression line into my data. What I want is to transform the serie B to be similar to the serie A, by applying a linear function to all its components. So it's like "what number m i have to multiply all values of serie B and what number n i have to add in order the serie B fitting the serie A". As an example, if A=(7,7,7,7) and B=(3,3,3,3), then all values of B should be multiplied by 2 and added 1, so B'=(7,7,7,7). (m=2, n=1).

Comment: However, my problem comes when A=(7,8,7,7) and B=(3,3,3,3). I want the m and the n that give the maximum correlation between A and B

Comment: Yes, linear regression gives you that. It gives you the equation of a line, that is to say $A=mB+n $, which best fits your data. Applying the equation to $B $, you can transform $B $ into data that are close to $A $. In your example $A=(7,7,7,7) $  and $B=(3,3,3,3) $, linear regression would give the line $A=2B+1$, which is what you are searching.

Comment: Was my comment useful to clarify?